# Take only local value not global one, when calling a global variable

Tags: javascript

I have some trouble with a global variable that is not using the local value of a variable I set inside a function because when I call it, it takes the global or default value of such a variable, but not the local one. *I hope this could be understandable*.

**I set my global variables**, *which I'm gonna use on several functions*:

```
params = {
    max: 1,
    time: 10*1000,
    errors: ['time']
}

timeoutmessage = '**Error:** You did not reply, so you are probably playing with me. I only wait for reply for ' + params.time / 1000 + ' seconds. So, I understand your nothingness as a yes. Therefore, I will get outta here. Goodbye!'
```

Then, **I set the value of *time* on *params* JS object locally**, *and I also `console.log` it*:

```
params['time'] = 20*1000

console.log('Time value: ' + params.time);
```

Finally, **I summon the global variable locally**, *which I desire, that it employs the local value*:

```
message.channel.send(timeoutmessage);
```

Although, when the global variable is summoned it gives me:

> **Error:** You did not reply, so you are probably playing with me. I only wait for reply for 10 seconds. So, I understand your nothingness as a yes. Therefore, I will get outta here. Goodbye!

Even though, when the `console.log` says me:

> Time value: 20000

Therefore, the global variable (*timeoutmessage*), is only taking global, not the local one.

***However, I don't know how to solve this. Any reply will be grateful.***

Comment: `params.time` and `timeoutmessage` are two completely different things. Why do you expect the two to be the same?

Comment: @VLAZ Yeah, they are. I don't expect them to be the same. I want that the timeout message tells the amount of time the script can wait for a reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
params = {
    max: 1,
    time: 10*1000,
    errors: ['time']
}

getTimeOutMessage = function(){
    return params.time /1000;
}
```

```
params['time'] = 20*1000

message.channel.send(getTimeOutMessage());
```

Answer (score 0):

As the params is an object, pass by reference will occur and that will change the original object in the global variable. Try to pass a deep/shallow copy of the params object to other functions:

- Deep Copy: `const copyParams = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(params));`
- Shallow Copy: `const sCopyParams = Object.assign({}, params);` or `const sCopyParams = {...params};`